# How to manage TabBarController on new view after viewController push action

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a problem building applicatin with tabBarController.
There is no problem doing tabBarController with navigationController if I build it from AppDelegate.

But now I have experienced problem when I want to create new view with tabBarController (3 tabs and each has navigation controllers) after a push from previous navigation controller.
It simply doesnt work.

Here is the code:

```
MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
mainViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"First";
UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

DictionariesViewController *dictionariesViewController = [[DictionariesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DictionariesView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
dictionariesViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Second";
UINavigationController *dictionariesNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dictionariesViewController];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainNavigationController, dictionariesNavigationController, nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

There is a problem after view is pushe to "First" controller. Application crashes...

Please for help.

Regards
Borut

Comment: Please reformat your code. It's hard to read the code as is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do with the following code?

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

You said that your app has 3 tabs and each of those tabs have a navigation controller. Therefore, what you should do is to add the navigation controllers to `tabBarController.viewControllers` (which you did), but then you need to set the `tabBarController` as the root view controller.

Comment: Yes, my app has 3 tabs and every one of them has his own navigatonController. I add one navigationController and view controller to each tabBarController.
At the end I pushed everything on new view: [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES]; What do you mean that I need to set tabBarController as root view controller? Can you give me a piece of code showing how to do that ? Thanks

Comment: In your app delegate, do the following after adding all the nav controllers to the tabBarController.

`[window setRootViewController:tabBarController];`

Comment: The problem is that I dont create tabBarController in AppDelete but on first subView. So there I can not access window property.

If I summarize in short. In AppDelegate I first push navigationController and some view in in. After a button push in view I create tabBarController and I push it here and I'm not anymore in AppDelegate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have done it this way and it works:

```
registerViewController = [[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterView_iPhone" bundle:nil];
AppDelegate_Phone *delegatePhone = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegatePhone.firstViewController.navigationController pushViewController:registerViewController animated:YES];
```

Thanks for your help guys.